# Potential Outcome Framework Notation for ATE's

Tags: econometrics, experiment-design, causality

I am trying to understand/maintain standard notation for Average Treatment Effects (ATE) in the potential outcome framework. Am I representing ATE correctly? Are these even the correct formulas? What would similar formulas for estimating ATE/ATT/LATE for other popular quasi-experimental techniques like regression discontinuity, IV, etc. look like? I'm looking for a list of formulas for estimating the treatment effects for these techniques all using the exact same notation (and ensuring what I already have is correct). I understand I might be missing the i's in the Diff-in-diff notation.

Where $Y_i (t=1)$ is the outcome if treated and $ Y_i (t=0) $ if not treated, and $X$ is the treatment and $Y$ is the outcome:

Average Treatment Effect of X on Y:
$ ATE = E(Y_i (1)|X_i  = 1) – E(Y_i (0)|X_i =0) $

Difference-in-difference ATT:
$ATT = (E(Y(1)|X = 1) – E(Y(0)|X = 1))  -  (E(Y(1)|X = 0) – E(Y(0) |X=0)) $

Regression discontinuity: ATE = ?

Instrumental Variable: ATE = ?